# Convert txt file to csv [only specific contents that matches a string pattern]

Tags: r, stringr

**I have a *.DAT file which can be opened by txt editor. I want to extract some contents from this and convert it to *.csv. The converted csv file must have header (colnames), specification (lower and higher) and  data portion. I need to convert 100's of these type of files to *.csv (as separate csv or all combined to one big csv file)**

**Sample snippet of my *.DAT file will look like below**

```
[FILEINFO]
VERSION=V4.0
FILENAME=TEST.DAT
CREATIONTIME=2015-07-09 22:05:26

[LOTINFO]
LotNo=A6022142  
DUT=BCEK450049
PRODUCTNAME=EX061
Order=
ChipCode=
SACH_NO=B39000-
MAT_NO=B39000-P810

[SPEC1]
TXT=SEN1
Unit=
LSL=-411.400000
USL=-318.700000

[SPEC2]
TXT=SEN2
Unit=
LSL=-11.000000
USL=11.000000

[SPEC3]
TXT=SEN3
Unit=
LSL=-45.000000
USL=10.000000

[DATA]
 2,29,-411.232,10.193,-11.530,
 3,29,-411.257,10.205,-11.328,
```

I can extract the contents below [DATA] and save in csv file. I am not sure how to extract the contents above to create header, etc. I used below code to extract contents below [DATA]

```
       library(stringr)
       library(readr)

       myTXT <- read_file("EXAMPLE.DAT")

       ExtData <- read.csv(text = 
           sub(".*\\[DATA\\]\\s+", "", my_txt), header = FALSE)

       dat2csv <- write.csv(ExtData, dat_2_csv.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

To extract the contents above [DATA] I tried below code with no success

```
        con <- file("EXAMPLE.DAT","r")
        OneLine <- c()

        while(True) {
          line = readLines(con,1)
          if(length(line) == 0) break
          elseif(line="LSL=")
          RES <- str_split(line,"=",simplify=TRUE)
          lines <- RES[1,2]
        }
```

Expected output csv file as below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-a-dat-file-2620550), .DAT files are very generic files with very specific information. Therefore, and especially after looking at your sample snippet, I doubt there is a straightforward way to do the conversion (unless there's a package designed specifically to process similar data).

I can only give you my 5 cents of my general strategy to tackle this:

- For starters, instead of focusing on the .csv format, you should first focus on turning this text file into a table format.
- To do so, you should save the parameters in separate vectors/columns (Every column could be TXT, Unit, LSL, etc.)
- In doing so, each row (SPEC1, SPEC2, SPEC3) would be representing each datapoint with all its characteristics.
- Even so, looks like it also contains metadata, and you might, therefore, save the different chunks of data into different variables (file.info = read_file(x, nrows = 4))

Hope it might help a bit.

Edit: As said by @qwe, the format resembles a [.ini file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file). So a good way to start would be to open the file with a '=' delimiter:

```
data = read.table('example.dat', delim = '=')
```

Comment: looks like .ini file to me.